# Add a hidden field with an object value in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create an app where a user can manage a database of "Lost property" items. To do so I have a main page where all the items are displayed and I have a button per row to be clicked when the item is returned to the owner.

That button is submitting a form that should contain the ID value of the element that has been clicked so I trying to get something like

```
<input id="id_id" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{lostitem.id}}">
```

But I don't know how to pass that value to my form ! Here is my template :

```
{% for lostitem in lostitems %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{lostitem.id}}</td>
        <td>{{lostitem.description}}</td>
        <td>
            <form class="give-back-item-form" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{formGiveBackItem.as_p}}
                <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-xs btn-success buttonItems">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <!-- TRYING TO ADD A HIDDEN INPUT WITH THE ID AS VALUE -->
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my form from forms.py

```
class GiveBackItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    class Meta:
        model = ItemLost
        fields = ('id',)
```

And here is where I'm trying to get my $_POST['id'] and to update my object (I couldn't test this part as I'm not getting any POST information at the moment) :

```
from .forms import GiveBackItemForm
"""Defining our views"""
def item_list(request):
    formGiveBackItem = GiveBackItemForm()
    """Ordering objects by date of creation"""
    lostitems =   ItemLost.objects.filter(added_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('added_date')
    if request.method == "POST":
        """Giving back an item"""
        itemToGive = ItemLost.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('id'))
        itemToGive.giveBackItem
    """Returning our ordered objects to the view"""
    """Request = everything we receive from the user (in a form for example)"""
    return render(request, 'lostitem/item_list.html', {'lostitems': lostitems, 'formGiveBackItem' : formGiveBackItem})
```

Thanks for any help or remark about the code ! I'm just getting started and it was really hard to find anything helpful about my problem

EDIT : I managed to make it work by still using the Django ModelForm and the view to handle my form
Here is my code in my view :

```
def item_list(request):
"""Ordering objects by date of creation"""
lostitems = ItemLost.objects.filter(added_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('added_date')
"""To get data from the form"""
give_back_item_form = GiveBackItemForm(request.POST or None)
# check if form is valid
if give_back_item_form.is_valid():
    itemToGive = ItemLost.objects.get(pk=give_back_item_form.cleaned_data['id'])
    itemToGive.returned_date=timezone.now()
    itemToGive.save()
# your rest of the code here
"""Returning our ordered objects to the view"""
"""Request = everything we receive from the user (in a form for example)"""
return render(request, 'lostitem/item_list.html', {'lostitems': lostitems, 'give_back_item_form' : give_back_item_form})
```

And here is the code for my template !

```
    <form class="give-back-item-form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ lostitem.id }}">
        <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-xs btn-success buttonItems">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true">    </span>
        </button>
    </form>
```

Thank you all for your answers it lead me to the right solution !

Comment: Your form doesn't seem to have a submit button. How are you submitting it? It also doesn't have an `action` attribute to tell it where to post.

Comment: I just edited the post to add the button ( forgot to include it from my HTML) and the form submits to the same page so no action is defaulted to empty string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all you want to do is post back the `id` of an associated `ItemLost` object so that you can invoke a method on it (e.g., `giveBackItem()`), there's no need to use a ModelForm at all. Just use a normal HTML `<form>`, and manually put the hidden field in it:

```
<form class="give-back-item-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" value="Give Back">                       
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{lostitem.id}}">
</form>
```

So your complete template would become:

```
{% for lostitem in lostitems %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{lostitem.id}}</td>
        <td>{{lostitem.description}}</td>
        <td>
            <form class="give-back-item-form" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-xs btn-success buttonItems">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{lostitem.id}}">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It was in fact easier to still create a ModelForm even without using the class to display the form, then the form validation and request handle is performed by Django which I assume is better coding  Thank you for your response, I  tried it and it lead me the right way